# convert ASCII character array to UNICODE string

Tags: c#, c, user-interface, unicode, ascii

I am calling a c dll function in c# which returns a 64 bit ASCII character array, since c# uses UNICODE how do I convert the ASCII character array to a UNICODE string?

I have done this before by having the string in a struct because the function had a struct as one of its arguments as follows:

```
      public struct example
      {
        public uint ID;  
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        public string serialNumber;  
      }
```

I cannot use a structure this time as this new function has serialNumber as one of its arguments. I have declared the serialNumber as a string, then when the imported c function is called the program crashes, I reckon This data conflict is the cause of that?

Sorry if this question is a bit confusing trying my best to explain my problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi`

Comment: that throws up an error saying Ansi does on exist in the type System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet. sorry I'm new to programming

Comment: should I be adding that at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi` like this :

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi )]
public struct example
{
    public uint ID;  
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string serialNumber;  
}
```

You can also declare your string as a byte array and convert later using :

```
myString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString( byteArray );
```